# Loop until certain time then loop next bit of code

Tags: python, python-3.x, instagram, bots

I have a bot that likes instagram pictures based on Hashtag. The code to like the certain set of hashtags in contained in a loop. I would like it to like a certain set of hashtags from 7am - 11:30pm and then from 11:30pm - 7am like another set of hashtags using another bit of code in another loop. The bot would then run 24/7.

The code to the bot is this so far, This only likes one specific set of hashtags, i need to add in the second bit of code:

```
    import os
        import time
        import random
        from instapy import InstaPy
        from instapy import smart_run

    like_tag_list = ['hashtag1','hashtag2','hashtag3']

    insta_username = '########'
    insta_password = '########'

session = InstaPy(username=insta_username,
password=insta_password,
headless_browser=True)
#multi_logs=True)


session.login()

            try:
                while True:

            # actions

                    session.like_by_tags(like_tag_list, amount=9, interact=True)
                    session.unfollow_users(amount=random.randint(75, 100),
                                       InstapyFollowed=(True, "nonfollowers"),
                                       style="FIFO",
                                       unfollow_after=8 * 60 * 60, sleep_delay=600)
                    #session.unfollow_users(amount=random.randint(75, 150),
                                       #InstapyFollowed=(True, "all"), style="FIFO",
                                       #unfollow_after=24 * 60 * 60, sleep_delay=501)

            finally:
```

Can somebody help me with getting the bot to loop the first part of code from 7am - 11:30pm and then let me know where to add the second set of hashtags for the second loop. I would be very greatful.

Massive blurb,hope all makes sense.

Comment: Please fix all your indenting... Man is that hard to read.

Comment: Sorry i know its a mess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I edited your core loop a bit and it should work. Define two lists, one with the hashtags for one time period and the other for hashtags in the other time period. On each iteration of the while loop, get the current datetime before extracting the hour from it and doing if checks on the hour to put the correct hashtags based on that current time in the tags_to_use list, which is then used. One small issue is that I believe now.hour is an int so it wont support the 11:30pm time, i set it to 24 so it would be from 7 am till midnight.

```
import datetime
like_tag_list1 = ['hashtag1','hashtag2','hashtag3']
like_tag_list2 = ['hashtag3','hashtag4','hashtag5']
while True:
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    if now.hour >= 7 and now.hour < 24:
        tags_to_use = like_tag_list1
    else:
        tags_to_use = like_tag_list2
    session.like_by_tags(tags_to_use, amount=9, interact=True)
    session.unfollow_users(amount=random.randint(75, 100),
             InstapyFollowed=(True, "nonfollowers"),
             style="FIFO",
              unfollow_after=8 * 60 * 60, sleep_delay=600)
```

Comment: The `if` can be refined to `if 7 <= now.hour < 24:`

Comment: wow guys thank you so much. Amazing implementation, i will give it a try.